# python subprocess две последовательных команды в одном процессе

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

Необходимо отправить через cmd.exe последовательно две команды - set и запустить скрипт python.exe:

```
set_cmd='set GDAL_DATA=C:\\Users\\gammapopolam\\Anaconda3\\Library\\share\\gdal'
cmd=f'C:\\Users\\gammapopolam\\Anaconda3\\python.exe C:\\PROGRA~1\\Git....
```

пытался сделать так:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, call
proc = call(['cmd.exe', set_cmd, cmd], shell=True)
```

результатом второй команды должно быть создание файла в директории, но после работы скрипта он не создается.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно последовательно послать две команды в одном процессе cmd.exe?

Windows 8.1, Python 3.7.3, Spyder 4.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Наберите `cmd.exe /?` и читайте.

```
cmd.exe /c echo Hello&echo world
```